# Finding the distance beween two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_2=\{s=(s_0s_1s_2)|s_j=0\  \text{or} \ 1\}$, which is a sequence space of $0$ and $1$'s.

We make $\sum_2$ into a metric space as follows: for two sequences $s=(000\dots)$ and $r=(1010\dots)$, then the distance between them is

$$d[s,r]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2i}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac14}=\frac43$$

since the distance between two series $s, r$

$$d[s,r]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{|s_i-r_i|}{2^i}$$
is dominated by the geometric series

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}=2$$
But how did $2i$ end up in the exponent, and how did that denominator turn into $1-\frac14$?

Thanks

Comment: This is strangely worded. You say "We turn $\Sigma_2$ into a metric space as follows:" and then what follows is not a description of how you turn $\Sigma_2$ into a metric space. Also, I think you want a $\ldots$ in your definition of $\Sigma_2$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given $s,r$, $$|s_i-r_i|=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & : i \text{ is even}\\0 & : \text{otherwise}.\end{array}\right.$$

So $$d[s,r]=\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{0}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{0}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\ldots=\sum_{i\text{ even}}\frac{1}{2^i}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2i}}.$$  This is where the $2$ in the exponent comes from.

Next, we note that $2^{2i}=(2^2)^i=4^i$, so $\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=\frac{1}{4^i}$, and $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2i}}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^i}=\frac{1}{1-1/4}.$$  This is because $\sum_{i=0}^\infty r^i=\frac{1}{1-r}$ for $-1<r<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$|s_i - r_i| = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 2 \mid i, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Thus, $|s_i - r_i|=1$ if and only if $i$ is a multiple of 2.
Hence, we may write
$$
\sum^\infty_{i=0} \frac{1}{2^i} = \sum^\infty_{i=0} \frac{1}{2^{2i}}
$$
to keep the nonzero terms only. This is just a geometric series,
so
$$
\sum^\infty_{k=0} ar^k = \frac{a}{1 - r}
$$
for $|r| < 1$. Use $a = 1$ and $r = \frac{1}{4}$ to obtain the result.